Latest Woocommerce checkout page handler payment
I make a custom plugin that use an external api to calculate the shipping cost on the checkout page.
A custom shipping method created also. alla works as expected but when the user change the payment method the refresh of the total and calculation of the shipping cost is not working.
in a script we have this part of code to trigger when payment method changed :
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('change', 'input[name="radio-control-wc-payment-method-options"]', function() {
        var paymentMethodId = $(this).val();
        console.log('Selected Payment Method: ' + paymentMethodId);

        $.ajax({
            url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'update_chosen_payment_method',
                paymentMethodId: paymentMethodId
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Server responded: Success ');
                if (response.success) {
                    console.log('Payment method successfully updated in session.');
                    $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
                } else {
                    console.error('Failed to update payment method in session: ', response);
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error('AJAX request failed: ', error);
            }
        });
    });
});

and in the custom calculation function :
function calculate_shipping_cost($package) {

    $payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');
    error_log('Selected Payment Method: ' . $payment_method);

    // ........................
    $delivery_products = $payment_method === 'cod' ? 'COD' : null;
    $charge_type = $payment_method === 'cod' ? 4 : 2;

so for example when the payment method is cod we send to the API the payment method id adds an extra fee.
but not working any more in the latest updates in the WooCommerce as the payment method in the debug not captured as not refreshing as expected.
If I change the shipping method or the address then the refresh and calculation happens.
Could anyone help please, I m stuck in this issue more than a week.
debug file for payment method not captured:
[12-May-2024 18:31:40 UTC] Weight: 0.5
[12-May-2024 18:31:40 UTC] Payment Method:
